# Unable to update an array of ids

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hey so I'm working on a program that essentially finds tweets and favourites them.

It's successfully favouring the tweets on twitter, however not updating the boolean I'm trying to change.

```
not_favorited = self.favorites.all.where(:favorited => false)
not_favorited_ids = not_favorited.map(&:id)
tweet_ids = not_favorited.map(&:tweet_id)
self.twitter.favorite!(tweet_ids) && self.favorites.not_favorited_ids.update_all(:favorited => true)
```

does anybody know what I'm doing wrong here and how I can successfully save these? Also is there a better way to write this?

Comment: Try this `Favorite.where(id: not_favorited_ids).update_all(favorited: true)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
not_favorited = self.favorites.all.where(:favorited => false)
not_favorited_ids = not_favorited.map(&:id)
tweet_ids = not_favorited.map(&:tweet_id)
self.twitter.favorite!(tweet_ids) 
Favorite.where(id: not_favorited_ids).update_all(favorited: true)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
not_favorited = self.favorites.all.where(:favorited => false) 
not_favorited_ids = self.favorites.where(:favorited => false).pluck(:id) 
puts "start debug =-)" 
tweet_ids = not_favorited.map(&:tweet_id) 
puts "self.fav #{self.favorites.where(id: not_favorited_ids).first}" 
Favorite.where(id: not_favorited_ids).update_all(:favorited => true) 
self.twitter.favorite!(tweet_ids)
```

Edited, try now - and then show me result from ur console

Comment: Show me ur models with relationship

Comment: start debug =-)
self #<User:0x007fcfc0d254f0>
fav_ids [21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28]
  Favorite Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "favorites".* FROM "favorites"  WHERE "favorites"."user_id" = $1 AND "favorites"."favorited" = 'f'  [["user_id", 2]]
tweet_ids ["577924468548493313", "577924467302760449", "577924466665193472", "577924465440391168", "577924465092403200", "577924465046089728", "577924464903606272", "577924464882556928"]

Comment: so, if `self.twitter.favorite!(tweet_ids)` returns not `false` or `nil`, `self.favorites.where(id: not_favorited_ids).update_all(:favorited => true)` have to work, try just `Favorite.where(id: not_favorited_ids).update_all(favorited: true)` like @Sontya said before `self.twitter.favorite!(tweet_ids)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73253/discussion-between-legendary-and-sja).